# In a table, how can I have a certain cell content not influencing the width of a column?

Tags: tables

If I have a table, can I add a cell where the content doesn't influence the width of the column where it is placed (but rather just overflows the column if it's to narrow)?

Comment: I do not understand. Are you looking for something like merging neighbouring cells? What about `\multicolumn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the contents in a `\makebox[0pt]{...}` which doesn't have a width at all:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    Test & this\\
    \makebox[0pt]{marsupilami} & test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison here is what `\rlap` (as suggested by samcarter) would result in:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    Test & this\\
    \rlap{marsupilami} & test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also the command `\llap` which would result in the contents overlapping to the left instead of to the right.

Comment: My columns are not centred :)

Comment: @samcarter you don't but perhaps the OP has, and I just wanted to show the results in a comparable way... There is no rating of the two solutions intended.

Comment: As there is no MWE in the question I'm at the liberty to invent the alignment of my choice :)

Comment: @samcarter correct.

Answer (score 2):

Same idea [as Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/381323/36296), but instead of `\makebox` you could also use `\rlap` (or dpeneding on the column alignment `\llap` or `\clap`, see https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf) to get a box of zero width.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & b\\
\rlap{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} & b\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\clap` is not defined in `article` you'd need packages for that one.

Comment: @Skillmon That's why I put the link there

Comment: `\clap` is defined by `mathtools` – together with `mathclap`, `\mathrlap` and `\mathllap`.